# Is there any log(n) time cost Set which iterate in order to insertion (in Java)?

Tags: java, set, time-complexity

I need a Set which has `log(n)` time cost for add, remove, and contains methods and it iterate in order to element insertion. The `Treeset` can do this? and how? I know that `LinkedHashList` can do it, but has no `log(n)` time cost.

Comment: LinkedHashSet is O(1) for these operations; you specifically want something that is slower (asymptotically)?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html

Comment: My task is to create own container which use Set, and this Set cost main operations has to lower or equal log(n) cost.

Answer (score -1):

The TreeSet can do this. Internally it uses A Red-Black tree implementation for storing the elements thereby providing asymptotic guarantees of O(log n) for insertion/deletion/searching elements.

- Insertion - O(log n)
- Deletion  - O(log n)
- contains  - O(log n)

For iterating through the list there are 2 types of iterators available :

```
Iterator<E>     iterator()
Returns an iterator over the elements in this set in ascending order.

public Iterator<E> descendingIterator()
Returns an iterator over the elements in this set in descending order.
```

You can refer the documentation [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html)

Comment: _The elements are ordered using their natural ordering, or by a Comparator provided at set creation time_